# Transformer seq2seq model and loading embeddings from XLM-RoBERTa

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, sequence-to-sequence, machine-translation, transformer

Is it possible to feed embeddings from XLM- RoBERTa to transformer seq2seq model? I'm working on NMT that translates verbal language sentences to sign language sentences (e.g Input: He sells food. Output (sign language sentence): Food he sells). But I have a very small dataset of sentence pairs - around 1000. And the language is a low resource language.

I am a new researcher on the field of deep learning. Please help with your valuable advice.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed possible, but the question is if it is a good idea.

[FairSeq](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq) already contains a pre-trained XLM-R model, you can use by creating a new model: just copy the most suitable existing one and replace the encoder with XLM-R.

Another option would be using [Huggingface's Transofrmers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) that also provides basic support for sequence-to-sequence models as they show in [their blog post](https://medium.com/huggingface/encoder-decoders-in-transformers-a-hybrid-pre-trained-architecture-for-seq2seq-af4d7bf14bb8).

Now, why I don't think it is a good idea. Recent papers show that:

1. Improving MT with pre-trained Transformers requires a lot of effort and it is still questionable whether it pays off, see [Incorporating BERT into Neural Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06823)
   .
2. The encoder of MT capture different structures: see [What does BERT look at?](What does BERT look at?) and [Analyzing Multi-Head Self-Attention:
   Specialized Heads Do the Heavy Lifting, the Rest Can Be Pruned](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W19-4808.pdf).
3. In an end-to-end trained translation system, a large part of the translation process is happening already in the encoder, see [Analyzing Word Translation of Transformer Layers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09586).

I assume you only have little training data and therefore you hope that pre-trained representation might help, but I believe you should put more effort in optimizing an end-to-end model to work in low-resource setup (have a look at [Revisiting Low-Resource Neural Machine Translation: A Case Study](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11901)) and data augmentation technique like iterative back-translation that it used in unsupervised machine translation.